# spi.SqlExceptionHelper warning in console logs when using db2 9.X database, java 8 and hibernate 4.3.8

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, db2, java-8

I get the following warnings in my console logs when using db2 9.X database, Java 8, hibernate 4.3.8 and Spring 4.15

```
|WARN|spi.SqlExceptionHelper|http-bio-8080-exec-9|SQL Warning Code: 4223, SQLState:null
|WARN|spi.SqlExceptionHelper|http-bio-8080-exec-9|Origination unknown: [10228][11541][4.14.137] Security exceptions occurred while loading driver. ERRORCODE=4223, SQLSTATE=null
```

This happens for every CRUD operation. Does anyone know what this means?

Answer (score 5):

Came across this link, might help you:

- it seems like db2 and J8 are "partially" compliant in this way
- however by switching to new versions of the driver (e.g. 4.19.26 from fix pack 5) the exception should disappear

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sql-workbench/ha26NSwmSQc

Comment: i was using spring-boot JPA and had the same error... updated the driver from 4.16.53 to 4.19.49 and now it's ok, tks!

Comment: @Hinotori - am facing similar issue. Can you pls elaborate on updating the driver? Am using pom from https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/ibm/db2/jcc/db2jcc4/10.1/.

Comment: @csharpnewbie i´m not using this anymore but i think i can help you. Go to this page http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866 and download an upgraded version. Note that since IBM´s db2 driver is not on maven central, you have to register it on your machine or local nexus, like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34721896/maven-external-dependency/34721958. If you´re using spring-boot 1.5.x i would upgrade it too

Comment: I upgraded to version 4.21.29 and still see this warning in JDK 1.8 + Tomcat 8.5.  Oddly enough, the log line mentions version 4.14.146

Comment: Please note that db2 driver is on maven central now:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.db2/jcc